# How can I design a circuit that will generate a sinc function?

Tags: analog, communication, function-generator

sinc function is given by sinx/x. How can i design a circuit to generate such type of signals what concepts should be used?

Comment: How will you deal with negative time? Just use stored values and a DAC.

Comment: A filter which removes/suppresses all the frequency components above a given BW can be a sinc generator. I think it can't be an analog circuit. So a DSP is needed or -as Andy suggested- can be generated with a DAC & look up table.

Comment: Do you *really* want a real sinc function, or is a decaying sine wave starting at its positive peak good enough?

Comment: @RohatKılıç: The coefficients of an FIR brick-wall low-pass filter *ARE* a sinc function, so implementing a filter (and driving it with an impulse) and doing a table lookup end up being essentially the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make two log amps, into one put a ramp signal, into the other put a sine wave. then the two signals go through an analog subtractor circuit, then an anti-log amp and voila -- sinc pulse. But it does have it's limitations and the inputs are of necessity pretty low.

easiest way is still the lookup table, that is the way it's done even on medical equipment like magnetic resonance machines.

Comment: You can use the tool and draw schematics. Kind of useful, it also simulates.